# reusable UIBarButtonItem in all View Controllers in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I making custom navigationBar with background color and font size. In addition i have add menu button on right. For this I had made the category named

UINavigationController+Transparent.h

```
 @interface UINavigationController (Transparent)
   - (void)presentTransparentNavigationBar;
   - (void)hideTransparentNavigationBar;
 @end
```

UINavigationController+Transparent.m

```
#import "UINavigationController+Transparent.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Transparent)

UIBarButtonItem *menuButton;

- (void)presentTransparentNavigationBar;
{
menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showMenu:)];

    [menuButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton;


UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[backButton setImage:backButtonImage
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);

[backButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(popViewController)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;


    [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor wolfRed]];
    [self.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
        @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19.0] }];
    [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}


- (void)hideTransparentNavigationBar
{
  [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:[[UINavigationBar appearance] isTranslucent]];
  [self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] shadowImage]];
}
@end
```

inside my ViewControllers i call

```
[self.navigationController presentTransparentNavigationBar];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController hideTransparentNavigationBar];
```

The problem is that menu button is not visible and back button is seems like standard iOS blue back button.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

> See I used to customize my navigation bar in following way with
> objective c

Step.1 Make sure your View Controller is embed in Navigation Controller

[image]

Step.2 Add required icons in your assets eg. "menu_icon" and "back"

Step.3 with the objective-C you can customize navigation bar as like you want.

I always do this way,

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController (){UIBarButtonItem *menuButton;}
@end


@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - life cycle methods
- (void)viewDidLoad {[super viewDidLoad];}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}

#pragma mark - IBAction methods
- (IBAction)showClicked:(id)sender {[self presentTransparentNavigationBar];}
- (IBAction)hideClicked:(id)sender {[self hideTransparentNavigationBar];}

#pragma mark - Navigation Bar methods

//Customize Naviagtion Bar
- (void)presentTransparentNavigationBar;
{
    //Add Menu Button to Navigaiton Bar
    menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showMenu:)];
    [menuButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton;
    
    
    //Add Back button to Navigation Bar
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:backButtonImage
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
    [backButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(popViewController)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    
    //Config Navigaton bar settings
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];//I used light gray color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19.0] }];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}


//Hide Navigation Bar
- (void)hideTransparentNavigationBar
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:[[UINavigationBar appearance] isTranslucent]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] shadowImage]];
}

- (void) showMenu:(id) sender{ /*TODO when clicks on Menu button */ }
- (void) popViewController{    /*TODO when clicks on Back button */ }

@end
```

and if managed everything proper you should be able to get Menu and Back button to navigation bar when you click show button on the screen.

[image]

## Note:

you can do this in your AppDelegate file so it will available in entire application

Comment: it's very good answer! But how I can user the same Menu button on every ViewController without copying the code in every view?

Comment: thank you!! you need to use same logic in your AppDelegate's method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Can intialize UINavigationViewController without defining rootviewController in appdelegate?